# "Near equivalence" of semigroups and monoids

Tags: semigroups, monoid

Given any semigroup $S$ we can uniquely extend it to a monoid $M$ by introducing a new identity element (even if $S$ already has an identity we can still add a new identity). Conversely, given a monoid $M$ we can forget it's current identity to get a semigroup $S$, and these two operations are inverse to eachother. However this is not a functor, so we cannot really call semigroups and monoids equivalent. However it feels like anything done in a semigroup can be done in a monoid and vice versa using this operation. Is there a name for this "near equivalence"?

Comment: How do you forget the identity of a monoid? For instance, you certainly can't select a multiplicatively closed subset of a finite group without including the identity, and if it's just a formal trick like "a monoid is a pair $(S,1)$ of a semigroup and a two-sided identity" plus the map being the "forgetful" functor $(S,1)\mapsto S$, then adjoining an identity (as you said, regardless of there being one in $S$ already) is not its inverse.

Comment: @Gae.S. true, this was a mistake from me. However, if we instead of monoid considered this structure of a $(S,1)$ where $S$ semigroup and $1$ identity, wouldn't adjoining an identity be, "up to isomorphism" an inverse?

Comment: @answermyquestions No: for instance, if you add a new identity to the one-element group $\{e\}$, you end up with the monoid $\{e',e\}$, with operations $e'e=ee'=e$, $e^2=e$, $(e')^2=e'$, which is the monoid $(\{0,1\}, \lor, 0)$.

Comment: @Gae.S. If you then remove either $e'$ or $e$ from it, you get back either $\{e\}$ or $\{e'\}$ which is isomorphic to what you first had: $\{e\}$

Comment: $e$ is not an identity of the new $\{e',e\}$, because $e'e\ne e'$. Anyways, there are three things on the table (*maybe* up to iso) and you are mixing them: (A) given a semigroup $S$, adding a new identity $e'$ and considering the (iso class of) monoid $(S,e')$; (B) given a monoid $(M,e)$, considering the (iso class of) $M$; (C) given a monoid $(M,e)$, considering $M\setminus\{e\}$. *continued...*

Comment: *... continues* I have already refuted $(C)$, because $M\setminus\{e\}$ won't be multiplicatively closed in general (see finite groups, where any similar construction fails catastrophically). Throughout your exposition you have always spoken of constructions which are *inverse of each others*, and therefore that would mean to me that $A\circ B=B\circ A=Id$ up to something. I refuted that by showing that applying first $B$ and then $A$ may not return the original isomorphism class. The fact that $C$ might be defined on the image of $A$ and that $C\circ A$ might be the identity is a new one.

Comment: Also, if I were you, I would inspect the possibility that the notion that best suits your goal might be: (D) given a semigroup $S$, add a two-sided identity if there isn't any, or leave it as it is if there is one.